# Error with variable array size using the visual C++ compiler (Visual Studio 2010). How to circumvent this issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

I am experiencing some troubles compiling a c++ file that worked well as a previous build under GCC. 
The issue is, I am using vectors of variable array size:

```
unsigned int howmany;
std::vector<int>* array_adresses[howmany];
```

I am currently using the Visual-Studio 2010 C++ compiler to built Matlab 64-bit Mex-Files. 
Since VC++ won't allow me to use arrays whose size is unknown at compile time, I am receiving the following error messages:

error 2057: constant expression expected
error 2466: 
error 2133: unknown size

Is there any way to build the 64 bit mex file using a GCC-compiler option or build it with a different 64-bit compiler under Matlab?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are declaring an array of pointers to `vector<int>`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Lord Flashback: Correct? Maybe. Ugly? Definitely :) Why not use a vector of pointers to vector instead?

Comment: Yes, that might be a way to avoid the variable array-size issue. The question still remaining is whether I can sucessfully compile the current program without introducing major changes in my code.

Comment: Well then do it how it is always done. `std::vector<int>** array_adresses;` then somewhere before you use it `new` it up. Another way to see this is: How much space should the compiler allocate for your array if it doesn't know the size at compile time?

Comment: _How much space should the compiler allocate for your array if it doesn't know the size at compile time?_ Well, without knowing too much about the inner workings of VC++-compiler I can confirm that GCC allows the definition of one-dimensional arrays with variable size. So does Fortran (even multidimensional!). When I allocate a new array using `new array[varsize]` VC++ won't throw an error if varsize is not known at compile time, will it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

howmany needs to be constant, and needs to be a defined amount, like so:

```
const unsigned int howmany = 5;
std::vector<int>* array_adresses[howmany];
```

Or you can define it dynamically like this:

```
unsigned int howmany = 5;
std::vector<int>* array_adresses = new std::vector<int>[howmany];
```

Comment: This is were it's all about, howmany is an unknown parameter. It's passed as input argument through into the Mex-Function Stack.

Comment: @Lord Flashback Just set howmany to the input argument and create array_addresses dynamically.

Comment: To get it right: With dynamically you mean memory allocation on the heap instead of the stack with unknown memory size?

Comment: @Lord Flashback Well I'm not familiar with using Matlab, but going with what your'e doing, this is what I mean by dynamically:

unsigned int howmany;
std::vector<int>* array_adresses = new std::vector<int>[howmany];

Comment: @leeetNightshade: Yes, dynamic allocation on the heap works nicely and I could implement it without making major changes in my code!

Comment: Good to hear! :)   (P.S. If my answer helped, could you perhaps accept the answer by clicking on the arrow? ;p )

Answer (score 2):

C++ standard doesn't allow variable-length arrays. Lets take this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[argc];
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with `g++ foo.cpp`, but fails if you require a strict standard compliance.

`g++ foo.cpp -std=c++98 -pedantic`:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
foo.cpp:8: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a’
```

You should use `vector<vector<int> *>` or `vector<int> **` instead as others already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace
`int ptr[howmany];`
with
`vector<int> ptr(howmany);`
to obtain also automatic deallocation at the end of the scope.